# conda force non regression of python version

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, anaconda, conda

I am creating a conda env and specifying that I want python 3.6 inside:

```
$ export PYTHON_VERSION=3.6
$ source ~/virtualenv/python2.7/bin/activate
$ python --version
Python 2.7.14
$ pip --version
pip 9.0.1 from /home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.14/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
$ wget -q http://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O miniconda.sh
$ chmod +x miniconda.sh
$ ./miniconda.sh -b -p /home/travis/miniconda
$ export PATH=/home/travis/miniconda/bin:$PATH
$ conda update --yes --quiet conda
$ conda env create --file environment.yml python=${PYTHON_VERSION}
```

However, this install python 2.7:

```
conda env create --file environment.yml python=${PYTHON_VERSION}
Fetching package metadata ...........
Solving package specifications: .
... omitting some packages here 
python-2.7.16- 100% |################################| Time: 0:00:00  74.39 MB/s
... omitting some other packages
```

Here is environment.yml:

```
name: my-env

dependencies:
    - ipython
    - numpy>=1.12
    - seaborn>=0.7
    - scipy>=0.18.0
    - matplotlib>=2.0.0
    - Cython>=0.26
    - scikit-learn>=0.20.1
    - tqdm
    - nose
    - numpydoc
    - pytest
    - pytest-cov

    - pip:
        - "https://api.github.com/repos/choldgraf/download/zipball/master"
```

What is going on? and how to impose the correct version of python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** Adding the wanted python version inside the `environment.yaml` downloads and installs the desirable python version.

```
name: my-env

dependencies:
  - python=3.6.8
  - ipython
  - numpy>=1.12
  - seaborn>=0.7
  - scipy>=0.18.0
  - matplotlib>=2.0.0
  - Cython>=0.26
  - scikit-learn>=0.20.1
  - tqdm
  - nose
  - numpydoc
  - pytest
  - pytest-cov

  - pip:
    - "https://api.github.com/repos/choldgraf/download/zipball/master"
```

**OR**

1. Create the environment with the correct python version
   `conda install --name my-env python=${PYTHON_VERSION}`
2. Update the environment with the `environment.yaml`
   `conda env update --file environment.yaml`

T̶h̶e̶ ̶r̶e̶a̶s̶o̶n̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶M̶i̶n̶i̶c̶o̶n̶d̶a̶.̶s̶h̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶ ̶d̶o̶w̶n̶l̶o̶a̶d̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶ ̶P̶y̶t̶h̶o̶n̶ ̶2̶ ̶b̶u̶i̶l̶d̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶n̶o̶t̶ ̶P̶y̶t̶h̶o̶n̶ ̶3̶.̶
̶

̶Y̶o̶u̶ ̶w̶a̶n̶t̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶g̶e̶t̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶M̶i̶n̶i̶c̶o̶n̶d̶a̶3̶.̶s̶h̶ ̶f̶r̶o̶m̶ ̶h̶t̶t̶p̶s̶:̶/̶/̶r̶e̶p̶o̶.̶c̶o̶n̶t̶i̶n̶u̶u̶m̶.̶i̶o̶/̶m̶i̶n̶i̶c̶o̶n̶d̶a̶/̶M̶i̶n̶i̶c̶o̶n̶d̶a̶3̶-̶l̶a̶t̶e̶s̶t̶-̶L̶i̶n̶u̶x̶-̶x̶8̶6̶_̶6̶4̶.̶s̶h̶.̶
̶

̶H̶o̶p̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶ ̶h̶e̶l̶p̶s̶.̶
̶

̶E̶d̶i̶t̶:̶ ̶I̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶n̶k̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶ ̶w̶i̶l̶l̶ ̶s̶e̶t̶ ̶u̶p̶ ̶M̶i̶n̶i̶c̶o̶n̶d̶a̶ ̶w̶i̶t̶h̶ ̶p̶y̶t̶h̶o̶n̶ ̶3̶.̶7̶.̶ ̶Y̶o̶u̶ ̶n̶e̶e̶d̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶m̶a̶n̶u̶a̶l̶l̶y̶ ̶c̶r̶e̶a̶t̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶3̶.̶6̶ ̶e̶n̶v̶i̶r̶o̶n̶m̶e̶n̶t̶ ̶w̶i̶t̶h̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶c̶o̶m̶m̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶c̶o̶n̶d̶a̶ ̶c̶r̶e̶a̶t̶e̶ ̶-̶-̶n̶a̶m̶e̶ ̶p̶y̶t̶h̶o̶n̶3̶6̶ ̶p̶y̶t̶h̶o̶n̶=̶3̶.̶6̶.̶8̶.̶
̶

̶Y̶o̶u̶ ̶c̶a̶n̶ ̶r̶e̶a̶d̶ ̶m̶o̶r̶e̶ ̶a̶b̶o̶u̶t̶ ̶c̶o̶n̶d̶a̶ ̶e̶n̶v̶i̶r̶o̶n̶m̶e̶n̶t̶s̶ ̶h̶e̶r̶e̶.̶
̶

Comment: But precisely, I am creating the environment with `conda env create --file environment.yml python=${PYTHON_VERSION}`. Why is python2.7 used ?

Comment: The thing is, I also need to isntall an env with python2. I have just tested, if I use miniconda3, then the env supposed to use python2 installs python3 too.

Comment: I thought you wanted to get Miniconda 3. The explicit command conda create -n python36 python=3.6.8 works when creating from miniconda2 a python 3 env for me.

Comment: I need both. This is for Travis automated testing. It also works locally for me.

Comment: Add the `python=3.6` package inside the `env.yaml`.
This downloads the correct version you want `python-3.6.8         | 20.3 MB   | #################################### | 100%`

Comment: I can't, I need the same environment.yml for both builds. The version is supposed to be set in the condo create command.

Comment: Conda has only one version of each package inside a environment. Python 2.7 is not a different package from python 3.6, it is just many versions behind it. Is it possible for you to have multiple envs, one with python 2 and one with 3, and an env2.yaml and a env3.yaml?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190292/discussion-between-geo-angelopoulos-and-p-camilleri).

Comment: May also be worth noting that if you create the env first with your specific Python version, then you can additionally [pin that version](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#preventing-packages-from-updating-pinning) to be extra careful that future installs/updates won't trigger a change.